# What L2-write bandwidth should I expect from a Nvidia Turing T4 GPU?

Tags: caching, cuda, nvidia, bandwidth

The microbenchmarking papers that I have found such as [1] and [2] report L2 bandwidths of 1200 GB/s and 900 GB/s respectively. I'm developing a kernel which attempts to leverage the L2 cache for global read *and* write operations.

So far, I have not been able to achieve a significant performance boost when writing to the L2 cache, as opposed to just writing to global memory.

Am I misunderstanding how the L2 cache operates? Is it unreasonable to even assume that both read and write bandwidth to be equivalent? Or is it that some non-straightforward methodology is needed to exercise the L2 write bandwidth properly?

[1] [Jia, Zhe, et al. "Dissecting the NVidia Turing T4 GPU via Microbenchmarking." arXiv (2019): arXiv-1903.](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/link_gateway/2019arXiv190307486J/arxiv:1903.07486)

[2] [Yan, Da, Wei Wang, and Xiaowen Chu. "Demystifying tensor cores to optimize half-precision matrix multiply." 2020 IEEE International Parallel and Distributed Processing Symposium, IPDPS. 2020.](http://home.cse.ust.hk/%7Eweiwa/papers/yan-ipdps20.pdf)